# How to remove the warning "fill out this field" and form auto cleanup

Tags: javascript, html, forms

can someone please help me to understand why the popup "fill out this field" keeps appearing when pressing the Add button?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
               
</head>
<body>

<style>
</style>

    <script>
    function removeInputField (selectedField) {
        selectedField.closest('.input_field').remove();
    }
    
    function addInputField () {
     var d1 = document.getElementById('expenses');
              d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="input_field"><input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="description[]"/><input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="amount[]"/><button onclick="removeInputField(this);">x</button></div>'); 
                }
                
                
                ///
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#submit').click(function(){
                      $.ajax({
                          async: true,
                          url: "sendData.php",
                          method: "POST",
                          data: $('#sendData').serialize(),
                          success:function(rt)
                          {
                              alert(rt);
                              $('#sendData')[0].reset();
                          }
                      });
                  });
              });
                ///
    </script>
              
              <form id="sendData">
    
    <button onclick="addInputField(this);">Add</button>
<div id="expenses">
    <div class="input_field"><input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="description[]"/><input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="amount[]"/><button onclick="removeInputField(this);">x</button></div>
</div>
 <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit"  class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, how can I edit the code to avoid the reset of the fields when the submit button is pressed?

Comment: You need to specify `type="button"` on your Add button or form will treat it as submit button, and you have required fields, so forms try's to submit, and require stops it and warns you. And i don't know what you mean by "reset of the fields when the submit button is pressed" I see no such behavior i n your code.

Comment: Many thanks! That worked! About the reset of the fields when the submit button is pressed, that happens only after the MySQL query is run. Unfortunately here it doesn't happen as the php file is missing